# Как делать спойлер?

Tags: обсуждение, markdown, сниппеты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как на скрине , в справке по markdown ни чего нету о этом

Comment: Никак, спойлер - это сниппет, на мете они отключены или не добавлены

Comment: а как же они появляются ? что надо сделать для этого ?

Comment: например, можно обратиться на мете с _предложением_ добавить к разработчикам

Comment: Grundy я только что сделал скрин на этом сайте

Comment: нет нет вот : http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554332/33274

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43816/discussion-between-grundy-and-geyan).

Comment: @Geyan это ж не Мета.

Comment: D-side , мне Grundy только что пояснил , но меня интересовал именно спойлер а мета это или нет мне до лампы , я ответ понял и знаю как

Answer (score 22, accepted):

В данном случае это не спойлер. Это сниппет, который по умолчанию свернут.

Для добавления сниппета нужно воспользоваться следующей кнопкой в режиме редактирования

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо воспользоваться горячими клавишами: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Далее поставить в меню слева галочку "Скрыть код по умолчанию"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]