# Что такое сниппеты?

Tags: обсуждение, редактор, сниппеты

Часто видел, что код в вопросах по web-дизайну оформлен в виде отдельного блока с кнопкой запуска. Что это и как сделать такое у себя?

**P. S.:** В вопросе «[Как делать спойлер?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3525/208074)» речь идёт о вставке свёрнутого сниппета. Здесь же спрашивается о том, *что это вообще такое.*

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как делать спойлер?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3525/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80)

Comment: @Grundy причем тут спойлер?

Comment: @alexolut, при том, что в том вопросе имелся ввиду сниппет, скрытый по умолчанию :-)

Comment: @Grundy речь об этом вопросе, а не о том :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Обычно код форматируют с помощью четырёх пробелов в начале каждой строки кода:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Однако, если код написан на языках HTML, CSS и JavaScript, имеется возможность воспользоваться расширенным форматированием с помощью так называемого *сниппета*:

*Да, ниже картинка. Сниппеты на Мете [не работают](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2276/208074), поэтому пришлось пойти на маленькую хитрость.*

[image: Образец сниппета]

Сниппет обладает следующим преимуществом над обычным, блочным форматированием кода: ***он позволяет объединять HTML, CSS и JS код воедино, давая возможность «живого», интерактивного предпросмотра получившегося результата***:

[image: Образец предпросмотра сниппета]

Для того, чтобы получить этот блок, необходимо воспользоваться следующим кодом:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: false babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

Код на JavaScript

<!-- language: lang-css -->

Стили на CSS

<!-- language: lang-html -->

Код на HTML

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Особенности:

- В HTML-коде допускается опускание следующих тегов:

  - `<html>`, если у него отсутствуют атрибуты или тег `<head>`,
  - `<html>` и `<body>`, если у `<body>` тоже отсутствуют атрибуты.
- Также допускается опускание и целых блоков `language`.

То есть подобная конструкция тоже допустима:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: false babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<p>Привет, мир!</p>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

И ещё. Заметили маленькую ссылку «редактировать пример кода» под сниппетом? При нажатии на неё открывается панель один-в-один как на JSFiddle:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Только добавлю, что тег `body` в разметку писать не надо - он там уже есть.

Comment: а блок с кодом вставляется перед закрытием тега body, поэтому нет нужды в onload

Comment: @Grundy, `onload` как раз таки имеет место быть (т.к. могут подгружаться сторонние ресурсы вроде картинок), а вот какой-нибудь `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')` действительно не нужен.

Comment: Сниппеты уже включили, можно убрать маленькую хитрость

Comment: @Grundy, включение сниппетов поломало форматирование блоков сырого кода (пример: «необходимо воспользоваться следующим кодом...»).

Comment: @Arhad, что-то не то

Comment: @Grundy, именно. Раньше это был блок кода с тегами `<!-- language: lang-js -->`, которые выводились как есть. А после включения поддержки сниппетов этот тег *стал интерпретироваться* **вне зависимости** от наличия четырёх пробелов перед ним.

Comment: @Arhad, поправил